# Are there Generic Enums in Java?

Tags: java, generics, enums

I'm trying to write a for-loop to iterate through an enum.  That part's simple, the format is:

```
  for( SomeDeclaredEnumType e : SomeDeclaredType.values() ){
      /*  do stuff here  */
  }
```

However, the part that's tricking me is iterating through a generic enum.  If I have TWO enums, one with 5 elements and one with 7, how do I tell Java to iterate through them? 
Essentially, I would like to do the following:

```
  Enum e;       // generic type enum
  FiveEnum f;   // enum with 5 elements
  SevenEnum s;  // enum with 7 elements

  switch (condition) {
      case 0:
          e = FiveEnum;   /*  assign e to FiveEnum  */
          break;
      case 1:
          e = SevenEnum;  /*  assign e to SevenEnum  */
          break;
  }

  For (Enum e : Enum.values()) {
      /*  iterate 5 or 7 times, depending on the case conditional  */
  }
```

Is there a way to do this?  A safe way to do this?  Preferably one using Generics from the Java library, as I'm not allowed to create a new enum. Thanks!

Comment: @JamesB That's not correct. Enums are classes and `Enum` is a generic type.

Comment: If you find yourself needing similar functionality often, that could be an indicator that those things shouldn't be enums.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Enum` is indeed a generic type; specifically, its type is `Enum<E extends Enum<E>>`. This is a bit confusing, but it means that every enum includes itself as a type parameter.

Your code could be written like this (assuming that `FiveEnum` and `SevenEnum` are declared somewhere else):

```
Class<? extends Enum<?>> enumClass = null;
switch (condition) {
case 0:
    enumClass = FiveEnum.class;
    break;
case 1:
    enumClass = SevenEnum.class;
    break;
}
for (Enum<?> e : enumClass.getEnumConstants()) {
    // loop body
}
```

Comment: can you explain how I'd do that?  Can I just add it inline with my class, like "private class E extends Enum{}"?  Please and thanks, very much.

Comment: Sorry, my original answer wasn't very clear; edited.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of declaring an `Enum e` to assign which class, use a `Class<? extends Enum<?>>`.  Then assign the proper class literal in each case statement.  Finally, in the bottom `for` loop, use [`Class`'s `getEnumConstants` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants--) to loop through all the enum constants.

```
Class<? extends Enum<?>> clazz;
int condition = 0;  // or 1

switch (condition) {
   case 0:
      clazz = FiveEnum.class;   /*  assign FiveEnum  */
      break;
   case 1:
      clazz = SevenEnum.class;  /*  assign SevenEnum  */
      break;
   // Added default case so clazz is always initialized.
   default:
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("" + condition);
}

for (Enum e : clazz.getEnumConstants()) {
   /*  iterate 5 or 7 times, depending on the case conditional  */
}
```